# A question on matrices from Golan's "Linear Algebra".

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question is given below:

> [image]

I feel like the answer is yes but I do not know how to justify it, could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: columns of $A$ are images of basis vectors

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The standard basis vectors have non-negative components, so, given the condition,

their images, which are the columns of the matrix, have non-negative components.

Comment: I do not think your answer is correct ..... I have a counter example for this.

Comment: @Smart:  feel free to post your counterexample, so it could be scrutinized

Comment: it is the matrix $2 \times 2$  matrix A that has entries in order 1, -1, 2 ,0 and the vector $v$ that has entries 1,1 ..... what is your opinion ? is my example wrong?

Comment: @Smart:     That matrix does not satisfy the condition that if $v$ is [any] vector...

Comment: the question say a vector not any vector

Comment: to satisfy the condition that if $v$ is a vector means it's true for any $v$

Comment: but this example shows that there is a vector for which this is not true.

Comment: the question is asking if all the matrix entries must be non-negative if the condition holds for all vectors; it is not asking if all the matrix entries must be non-negative if the condition holds for some vector

Comment: Got it thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes $a_{ij}$ is nothing  but the $i$-th coordinate of $Ae_j$ where $e_j$ has $1$ at the $j-$th place and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $v\neq 0$ be as in the exercise. Components of $Av$ are non-negative if and only if
$$
a_{i1}v_1 + a_{i2}v_2+...+a_{in}v_n \geq 0 \quad(i=1,...n)
$$
Assume one if it's entries, say $a_{pq}$ is negative. Then $a_{pq}v_q$ is also negative and if $v_{k}$  ($k \neq q$) are small enough, then
$$a_{p1}v_1 + a_{p2}v_2+...+a_{pn}v_n = a_{pq}v_q + \sum_{k \neq q} a_{pk}v_k < 0$$,
which equals to the first sum when $i=p$.